# Formatiing text inside tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, horizontal-alignment, tikz-styles

I am trying to align text inside the tikz node like in picture below. I tried to use tabular environment, but I wasn't successful. Is there a way to align text like that?

[image: example]

Code I wrote so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicure}
     \tikzstyle{status}=[draw,rectangle,rounded corners,fill=blue,text centered,inner sep=2pt]
     \node[status] (test) {
     \begin{tabular}{lcr}
     Word 1 & $\rightarrow$ & Value 1
     Word 2 & $\rightarrow$ & Value 2
     Word 3 & $\rightarrow$ & Value 3
     Word 4 & $\rightarrow$ & Value 4
     \end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Code expanded to MWE.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                matrix}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
 LA/.style = {line width=1mm, -{Triangle[angle=90:1pt 2]}, draw=blue!50!gray},
 BL/.style = {baseline=-0.75ex}
                    ]
\node[draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!30,
      inner ysep=3mm, inner xsep=2mm,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries, align=center,
      label={[font=\sffamily\bfseries,anchor=north west]north west:Example text}
      ]
{\\[2ex]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
 Word 1 & \tikz[BL]\draw[LA] (0,0) -- ++ (1,0); & Value 1 \\
 Word 2 & \tikz[BL]\draw[LA] (0,0) -- ++ (1,0); & Value 2 \\
 Word 3 & \tikz[BL]\draw[LA] (0,0) -- ++ (1,0); & Value 3 \\
 Word 4 & \tikz[BL]\draw[LA] (0,0) -- ++ (1,0); & Value 4 \\
 \end{tabular}
};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @awarus, if answer solve your problem on the best way, than you can accept it ... (by clicking on check mart at the top left side of answer) :-)

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear to me what your ultimate goal is but I recommend against putting `tabular` environments inside `\node`'s as there are usually better ways to do this. Of course, this really depends on what you are trying to do.

This said, if you do want to do this then you need to put a valid `tabular` environment inside the node. In particular, you need to end each row of the environment with `\\`. If you do this then your code produces what you want:

[image]

Here is the corrected code (which I have also expanded to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \tikzstyle{status}=[draw,rectangle,rounded corners,fill=blue,text centered,inner sep=2pt]
     \node[status] (test) {
     \begin{tabular}{lcr}
     Word 1 & $\rightarrow$ & Value 1\\
     Word 2 & $\rightarrow$ & Value 2\\
     Word 3 & $\rightarrow$ & Value 3\\
     Word 4 & $\rightarrow$ & Value 4
     \end{tabular}};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Taking inspiration from Zarko for the arrows, this is how I would probably do this.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, arrows.meta, backgrounds}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
        LA/.style={line width=1mm, -{Triangle[angle=90:1pt 2]}, draw=blue!50!gray},
        box/.style={rounded corners,fill=blue!30,text centered,inner sep=2pt, draw=MidnightBlue}]
     \foreach \word/\val [count=\c] in {Word 1/Value 1,Word 2/Value 2,Word 3/Value 3,Word 4/Value 4} {
       \node(word\c) at (0,-0.6*\c) {\word};
       \node(val\c) at (2.4,-0.6*\c) {\val};
       \draw[LA] (word\c)--(val\c);
     }
     \begin{scope}[on background layer]
       \node[box, fit=(word1) (val4)]{};
     \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

to produce:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. It was really helpful for me.

Comment: +1 for not nesting `tikzpictures`, which is a real improvement IMHO.